# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in chat

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nodejs

tengo este codigo:

```
$(document).ready(main2);
var mostrador = 1;
function main2() {
    $('.chat').click(function () {
        if (mostrador == 1) {
            $('.chat-base').animate({
                height: '500px'
            });
            document.getElementById('conversation').innerHTML="Hola";
        } else {
            mostrador = 1;
            $('.chat-base').animate({
                height: '0px'
            });

        }
    });
```

}

Pero al momento de ejecutarlo me sale el error que comente en mi pregunta, ¿cómo puedo repararlo? Gracias

Comment: Le id no existe o esta mal escrito

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido HTML sobre el que actúa ese código?

Comment: existe id="conversation" en tu código HTML ?